# Lost USB by dd-ing a bigger image on it

Tags: linux, usb, dd, read-only, ddrescue

I had a USB flash of 32GB with actual size of around 28GB. I put an image of 28.5GB containing 2 CentOS partition, which has some free space at the end of it. I thought it will not harm my USB. But after the dd command ended, my USB is bricked and in read-only state now. Is there anyway to recover my USB or should I giveup on it?

Comment: You cannot physically write a larger image to the device. `dd` will just just fail instead. // USB drives die, especially when heavily used.

Comment: `dd` (or Rufus, or balenaEtcher, or …) cannot directly break a USB flash drive (nor any drive). In general drives very rarely die randomly when being disconnected or idle, but they die randomly when being used. Overwriting a whole flash drive is a strain. The drive should survive it and it usually does; but if it's going to fail, it will probably fail during "heavy load", not when used "lightly".